# Radio button selection event in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a beginer ...I don't know how to write code during the radio button select change in MVC....I have used it like this

In csHTML page

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model=>Sales.Pay_Mode, true)Cheque
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model=>Sales.Pay_Mode, false)Cas
```

This is my cs page code....Where i want write the change event code and how i get the selected value in control page.My requirement is during radio button change i want change the style of the textbox enable as false..

```
@Html.TextBox("ChequeNo")
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering the information that you have provided in your question, the following code would fulfill your expectation

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.PayMode, "Cheque") Cheque 
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.PayMode, "Cas") Cas

@Html.TextBox("ChequeNo", null, new {id="theTextBox"})

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[name='PayMode']").change(function () {
        var selectedRadio = $("input[name='PayMode']:checked").val();
        if (selectedRadio == 'Cas') {
            $("#theTextBox").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
            $("#theTextBox").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The is no control events handler in MVC like in WebForms or something like this. You must use javascript code to implement your logic. For example with jQuery

```
$('.your-radio-class').change(function(){
    $('#your-textbox-id').css('margin-left', '100px')
});
```

Comment: sir pls tell what is the name of 'your-radio-class' in my project.where want to declare it

Comment: its just example css class yuo can define your own. For example try @Html.RadioButtonFor(model=>Sales.Pay_Mode, true, new {@class="own-class"})